# All Laravel routes "not found" on nginx

Tags: nginx

Trying to setup Laravel 4.1 installation on a nginx server (first time) and I'm given "not found" for every Laravel route instead of the view expected. The main page loads fine.

Please note, site can only be accessed by IP which is why I have the filler IP `123.123.123.123` for `server_name`.

etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
listen 80;

user  nginx;

worker_processes 4;

worker_rlimit_nofile 200000;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 4000;

    use epoll;

    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    include  /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include  /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

etc/nginx/site-available/mysite.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  123.123.123.123 "";
    access_log  /srv/www/mysite/logs/access.log;
    error_log  /srv/www/mysite/logs/error.log;
    root  /srv/www/mysite/public_html/public;
    rewrite_log  on;
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main buffer=16k;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    #gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript text/x-js;

    open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors on;

    sendfile on;

    tcp_nopush on;

    tcp_nodelay on;

    keepalive_timeout 90;

    keepalive_requests 100000;

    reset_timedout_connection on;

    client_body_timeout 30;

    send_timeout 30;

    # Remove trailing slash to please Laravel routing system.
    if (!-d $request_filename) {
        rewrite  ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # We don't need .ht files with nginx.
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

    # Set header expirations.
    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|jpe?g|JPG|png|svg|woff)$ {
        expires  365d;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had exactly the some problem like you.

I added this in my config file and finally it works now!

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the correct IP address in `server_name`, then your requests go to the nginx default vhost.

If you want your Laravel application to be the default ghost, add `default_server` to the `listen` directive in `mysite.conf`, and remove `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

Comment: The `listen 80;` entry at the top of nginx.conf is being rejected entirely now. Can't start the server with it there so I removed it. Now every time I visit the IP, it gives me the web page as a file to download instead of showing it like normal.

Comment: I also tried adding `default_server` to the listen directive in the mysite.conf file but that didn't fix.